# Speed up Python Script to populate MongoDB

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, mongodb

How would I go about making this script much faster? Essentially it reads from a file and the slowest part is populating the words. In the words file there are over 100k words and I was looking for a way to speed it up since this script is going to be used to populate the database with over 200 languages.

````py
import os, django
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE","eureka.settings")
django.setup()
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import admin
from wordDictionary.models import Genus, Word, Feature, Dimension, Language, Lemma, Family, TagSet, POS
import multiprocessing



# Dimensions
def dimensionPop():
    dimData = open("data/models/dimensions.txt","r")

    for x in dimData:
        a = x.split("\n")
        dimName = a[0]
        # Create Object 
        nextDim = Dimension(name=dimName)
        nextDim.save()
        #print(f":{nextDim.name}:")
    dimData.close()
    print("Dimension done")


# Features
def featurePop():
    featData = open("data/models/features.txt","r")
    for x in featData:
        line = x.split(";")
        featName = line[1]
        dimName = line[0]
        # Create Object 
        nextFeature = Feature(name=featName)
        dimObject = Dimension.objects.get(name=dimName)
        nextFeature.dimension = dimObject   

        #print(f"{nextFeature.dimension.name}")
        nextFeature.save()

    featData.close()
    print("Feature done")


# Part of Speech
def posPop():
    posData = open("data/models/POS.txt","r")
    for x in posData:
        line = x.split(";")
        posName = line[1]

        # Create Object 
        nextPOS = POS(name=posName)

        #print(f"{nextPOS.name}")
        nextPOS.save()
    posData.close()
    print("Part of Speech done")

# Genus
def genusPop():
    genusData = open("data/models/genus.txt","r")
    for x in genusData:
        genusName = x.split("\n")[0]
        # Create Object 
        nextGenus = Genus(name=genusName)

        #print(f":{nextGenus.name}:")
        nextGenus.save()

    genusData.close()
    print("Genus done")




# Family
def familyPop():

    famData = open("data/models/families.txt","r")
    for x in famData:
        FamilyName = x.split(";")[0]
        # Create Object 
        nextFamily = Family(name=FamilyName)

        #print(f":{nextFamily.name}:")

        nextFamily.save()
    famData.close()
    print("Family done")


def languagePop():

    #Populate only english for now
     nextLang = Language(name="English")
     nextLang.walsCode = "eng"
     nextLang.genus = Genus.objects.get(name="Germanic")
     nextLang.family = Family.objects.get(name="Indo-European")
     nextLang.save()

     print("Language done")


def lemmaPop():
    lemmaData = open("data/models/lemmas.txt","r",encoding="utf8")

    for x in lemmaData:
        x = x.split("\n")

        lemmaName = x[0]

        nextLemma = Lemma(name=lemmaName)


        langName = Language.objects.get(name="English")
        nextLemma.language = langName
        posName = POS.objects.get(name="Verb")
        nextLemma.pos = posName
        nextLemma.save()

    lemmaData.close()
    print("Lemma done")


findFeature={}
def readAppendix():
    fileContent =  open("data/models/features.txt","r")
    for row in fileContent:

        rowWords = row.split(";")
        dimension = rowWords[0]
        feature = rowWords[1]
        label =(rowWords[2].rstrip()).upper()
        findFeature[label]=feature # assign feature to label
    fileContent.close()
    print("\nStarting with words...")

usedTagset = {}

def wordPop():
    wordData =  open("data/langs/English.txt","r",encoding="utf8")
    it = 0
    for line in wordData:

        it += 1
        if it % 1000 :
            print(f"> {it}...")

        rowContent = line.split()
        if(len(rowContent)>=3): # checks if line is valid
            tagsetName = rowContent[-1]
            tagSetObject = None
            try:
                if usedTagset[tagsetName] == 1:
                    someTagset = TagSet.objects.get(name=tagsetName)
                    tagSetObject = someTagset
            except KeyError:
                usedTagset[tagsetName]=1
                tagSetObject = TagSet(name=tagsetName)


            rootWord = rowContent[0]
            currWordList = rowContent[1:-1] # it can be more than a single words

            currWord = ""
            for temp in currWordList:
                currWord += temp + " "
            currWord = currWord[:-1] # remove last space

            allLabels = tagsetName.split(";") # last block of words corrensponds to allLabels

            for currLabel in allLabels:
                try:
                    currFeature = findFeature[currLabel.upper()]
                    featObject = Feature.objects.get(name=currFeature)

                    tagSetObject.features.add(featObject)
                except KeyError:
                    print(f"{currLabel} label doesn't exist.")
        # print(tagSetObject.features.all())

        tagSetObject.save()

        # Defining the Word/Form


        wordObject = Word(name=currWord)

        lemmaObject = Lemma.objects.get(name=rootWord)
        wordObject.lemma  = lemmaObject
        wordObject.tagset = tagSetObject
        wordObject.language = lemmaObject.language
        # print(f"{wordObject.name} : {wordObject.lemma} : {wordObject.tagset} : {wordObject.language}")
        wordObject.save()
    wordData.close()




# *  uncomment below to populate !!in order!! *

dimensionPop()
featurePop()
genusPop()
posPop()
familyPop()
languagePop()
lemmaPop()
readAppendix()
wordPop()
#

# processes = []
# for _ in range(16):
#     p = multiprocessing.Process(target=wordPop)
#     p.start()
#     processes.append(p)

# for proc in processes:
#     process.join()

# Just in case it goes wrong

def emptyDatabase():

    Word.objects.all().delete()
    Lemma.objects.all().delete()
    TagSet.objects.all().delete()
    Language.objects.all().delete()
    Family.objects.all().delete()
    Dimension.objects.all().delete()
    Genus.objects.all().delete()
    POS.objects.all().delete()

    print("Database is empty...")


# emptyDatabase()


```
````

Comment: btw ``tqdm`` is a great module for reporting progress on a loop with very little overhead. Might be a good alternative to the manual iteration tracking in your word loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at `wordPop` since that's where you say the most time is being taken:

- I think your validity check is broken. There's an `if` statement to make sure the line is valid, but no `else`, and the code after the `if` uses variables defined within the conditional block.
- Use `" ".join(currWordList)` instead of manually concatenating a bunch of strings. That'll save you the creation of a bunch of intermediate string objects.
- You're storing values of `1` in `usedTagset`, but that's meaningless. What you're actually doing each time is fetching the object from the database. Sure, that's a "fast" lookup if the `name` field is indexed, but nowhere near as fast as just fetching the object from the dictionary. Instead, consider something like the following:

  ```
  if tagsetName not in usedTagset:
      usedTagset[tagsetName] = TagSet.objects.create(name=tagsetName)
  tagSetObject = usedTagset[tagsetName]
  ```
- Same thing for the `findFeature` chunk in the `allLabels` loop. If you're just doing a couple lookups, `.get` on an indexed column is super fast... but that's "fast" relative to database speeds. In this context, "fast" means a few milliseconds or most of a ms, most likely. That's completely intolerable when you're doing a loop of hundreds of thousands or millions of rows. Fetch the objects once, cache them in memory, and do direct lookups using a dictionary. You can initialize the cache as follows:

  ```
  usedTagset = {tag.name: tag for tag in TagSet.objects.all()}
  ```

  and then, as discussed above, save any newly created objects as you create them rather than re-fetch them each time. If you're not sure if something already exists in the database, use `get_or_create`:

  ```
  if tagsetName not in usedTagset:
      # get_or_create returns a tuple, the first element of which is the ORM object
      usedTagset[tagsetName] = TagSet.objects.get_or_create(name=tagsetName)[0]
  tagSetObject = usedTagset[tagsetName]
  ```

Cutting the DB and associated driver/network/ORM overhead out of the loop will likely be all you need to get reasonably performant code.

- I'm also a fan of `...objects.create`. It's more explicit that constructing the object one bit at a time.

  ```
  lemma = lemma_lookup[rootWord]
  Word.objects.create(
      name=currWord,
      lemma=lemma,
      tagset=tagSetObject,
      language=lemma.language
  )
  ```
- And finally, not performance related, but for the love of other Python developers, please follow [PEP8 naming conventions](https://realpython.com/python-pep8/#naming-conventions), particularly using lower-case underscore-separated names for variables; e.g., `word_object` instead of `wordObject`, and `tag_set_object` instead of `tagSetObject`.